# How to define a macro that can be used to log function calls in C?

Tags: visual-c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I found some code that is wrapping function calls with a macro `NAME()`,

```
#define NAME(x) x
...
m_strTemp.Format("x key:0x%X", NAME(a_function)(a_param));
```

The question is how to define NAME() macro so it will log the function being called using `TRACE()`.

Something like `#define NAME(x) TRACE("x");x` does not work because functions wrapped by NAME() macro may return things and sometimes they are used like the example above.

Note, this has to work with VC++ 2010 compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will probably do what you want:

```
#define NAME(x) (TRACE(#x), x)
```

(Note that you can enclose a function designator in parantheses, eg. `(strlen)("foo")` is allowed).

Comment: @sorin: No you don't.  The value of `NAME(x)(foo)` is the result of calling `x(foo)`.

Comment: @sorin:  Think about it: `a = NAME(x)(foo) ;`

Comment: TRACE is not in `gcc`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how TRACE works, but I would like to direct you to the `#` [macro quoting operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Quoting_macro_arguments).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a solution to your general question (related to [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)).

If you use GCC and if it is a recent version (4.6), you could consider making a GCC plugin which would replace some of your calls with e.g. a sequence of calls, that is which would replace inside the internal Gimple representation (internal to GCC) of your program, a call like `x=f(y,z)` with a sequence like `debugprint2(y,z); x=f(y,z); debugprint1(z)` etc.
But this is not very simple to code in C. You could consider coding that using [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a high level domain specific language to extend GCC). But extending GCC is not very simple anyway, and is worthwhile (needing a few weeks of work) only if your application is big enough

Answer (score 0):

For gcc there is a feature called [gcc function instrumentation](http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2010/09/gcc-function-instrumentation.html). It allows you to be notified for every function call and take an action (e.g. logging). Maybe you can import parts of your code to linux or maybe VS has a similar option.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar question in which I wanted to use the TRACE macros of Visual Studio 2005 to show logs in the output window when using the debugger.  However the source files were C source and not C++ nor did they use the MFC framework in any way so I was stuck.

Then I found this article [Debugging with Visual Studion 2005/2008: Logging and Tracing](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/visual_studio_trace_log_messages.html) which described first the TRACE macro and then some other mechanisms.  The one that I chose to use was the _RPT1() macro which allows me to put a TRACE type message into the output window of the Visual Studio debugger within a C source file.

It requires the inclusion of the crtdbg.h header file and just like the various TRACE macros, there are several different _RPT macros depending on the number of arguments.

This is not really an answer to this specific question however I wanted to document this way of getting debug output in Visual Studio 2005 as an alternative to the TRACE macros in a C source file.